# How to (can you) configure Azure API Management for Auth0 single page application

Tags: single-page-application, auth0, azure-api-management

Scenario: Auth0 Single Page application client. .NET Web API and Angular SPA both configured to use this client. Works great.

I'd like to add Azure API Management as a layer in front of the API. Have set up the API in the Management Portal, updated SPA to call API, tested calls from SPA, works great.

Now, I'd like to configure API Management Portal with the right security settings such that people can invoke API calls from the Developer Portal. I've used this [https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/azure-api-management/configure-azure] as a guide.

Where I'm at:

From the Developer portal, I can choose Authorization Code as an Auth type, go through a successful sign-in process with Auth0 and get back a Bearer token. However, calls made to the API always return 401. I think this is because I'm confused about how to set it up right. As I understand it:

- either I follow the instructions and setup a new API client in Auth0, but if that's the case then surely it's not going to work, because tokens generated from one client aren't going to work against my SPA client? (or is there something I need to change to make it work)
- or, how should I configure Azure API Management to work with a SPA application. (this would be my preferred method, having two clients in Auth0 seems 'messy'). But, don't I need an 'audience' value in my authorization endpoint URL? How do I get that?

If anyone has done this, would very much appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't think I'd be back to answer my own question quite so soon.  The reason is mostly rooted in my general ignorance of this stuff, combined with trying to take examples and fuse them together for my needs. Posting this to help out anyone else who finds themselves here.

Rather than take the Single Application Client in Auth0 and make it work with Azure API Management, I decided to go the other way, and make the non-interactive Client work with my SPA. This eventually 'felt' more right: the API is what I'm securing, and I should get the API Management portal working, then change my SPA to work with it.

Once I remembered/realised that I needed to update my audience in the API to match the audience set in the Client in Auth0, then the Management Portal started working. Getting the SPA to work with the API then became a challenge: I was trying to find out how to change the auth0 angular code to pass an audience to match the one the API was sending, but it kept sending the ClientID instead.  (by the way, finding all that out was made easier by using https://jwt.io/ to decrypt the Bearer tokens and work out what was happening - look at the 'aud' value for the audience.

In the end, I changed my API, in the `new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` object, the `TokenValidationParameters` object (of type `TokenValidationParameters`) has a property `ValidAudiences` (yes, there is also a `ValidAudience` property, confusing) which can take multiple audiences. So, I added my ClientID to that.

The only other thing I then changed (which might be specific to me, not sure) is that I had to change the *JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm* value in Auth0 for my non-interactive client (advanced settings, oAuth tab) from HS256 to RS256.

With all that done, now requests from both the API Management Portal, and my SPA work.

Curious to know if this is the "right" way of doing it, or if I've done anything considered dangerous here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're able to make the validation of the `jwt`s with the .Net API work, Only few changes are actually necessary to get this working with Azure API Management.

In API management, 
Create a `validate-jwt` inbound policy on an Operation (or all operations)
set the `audiences` and `issuers` the same as what you've used with your .NET web api. (you can check the values in Auth0 portal if you don't know this yet)

The important field that is missing at this point is the `Open ID URLs` since auth0 uses RS256 by default. The url can be found in you Auth0 portal at: Applications -> your single page application -> settings -> Scroll down, `Show Advanced Settings` -> End points. Then copy the `OpenID Configuration`

[Here's the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) for API management's requirement for JWT tokens

[optional reading](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/azure-api-management/configure-azure#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-for-access-tokens)